# setting BOOL variable inside block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to set a BOOL value which is defined in my class inside a block, but I can't see to be able to set it. This is the code.

```
 __weak __block SPTween *tween2weak = tween;
    __block BOOL buttonScroll2 = buttonScroll;

    tween.onComplete = ^{
        [Sparrow.juggler removeObject:tween2weak];
        buttonScroll2 = NO;
    };
```

I presume when I do `buttonScroll2 = NO`, all Im doing is setting a separate variable and not the original, but how do I get to the original from inside the block then?

Comment: ok but how do I set buttonScroll = NO; then from within the block?

Comment: Ah, I see what you call "the original" in your question - you mean `buttonScroll`! What is `buttonScroll` in your example?

Comment: Is it a local or an instance BOOL var?

Comment: I'm declaring it in the instance at the top inside {} but not in the .h and not in that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, once the value of `buttonScroll` gets copied into `buttonScroll2`, the changes to the `buttonScroll2` have no effect on the original `buttonScroll`.

If `buttonScroll` is an instance variable of your object, you should be able to access it using the `__weak self` pattern:

```
__weak __block SPTween *tween2weak = tween;
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
tween.onComplete = ^{
    [Sparrow.juggler removeObject:tween2weak];
    MyClass *strongSelf = weakSelf;
    strongSelf->buttonScroll = NO;
};
```

Comment: would weakSelf.buttonScroll work as well? or you have to use -> ?

Comment: Actually weakSelf->buttonScroll doesn't work as well, it's giving me the error "Dereferencing a __weak pointer is not allowed due to possible null value caused by race condition, assign it to strong variable first"

Comment: @Phil I edited to add a change that the compiler is asking to make.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that really is an area of obj-c that I don't like, too much messing around to do something simple.